# Passing array from JQuery to PHP via POST

Tags: php, jquery

I have two variables and an array I am attempting to pass to a PHP page. Unfortunately though I did do some searching, I cannot successfully pass my array. The variables work fine. Any help?

Heres my JQuery code:

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
        $.post('process.php', {primary: $prim, secondary: $seco, not: $not}, 
        function(data) {
            //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            $("#error").html(data);
        });
});
```

where

```
$not = {1,2,3};
```

**process.php**:

```
<?php
    require("common.php");
    $primary = $_POST['primary'];
    $secondary = $_POST['secondary'];
    $not = $_POST['not'];
    //echo("primary: "+$primary+", secondary: "+$secondary+", not: "+$not);
    echo($primary);
?>
```

**Error message**

```
Notice: Undefined index: not in C:\wamp\www\process.php on line 5
```

## Just realized maybe its because `not` is a keyword in php

Nope, it wasn't because of that

Comment: Your jQuery makes no sense to me because you don't show where your variables are coming from. Please post a complete example on jsfiddle for instance.

Comment: Use json and stringify and then decode it in PHP

Comment: @Sébastien I mentioned that only the array is having trouble being passed, the other variables are being passed just fine. I also showed that `$not` is the array. So where is the confusion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Your JQuery use  join(",")

```
$('#submit').click(function() {
        $.post('process.php', {primary: $prim, secondary: $seco, not: $not.join(",")}, 
        function(data) {
            //alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
            $("#error").html(data);
        });
});
```

And in your PHP use  explode() function to convert from string to array

```
<?php
    require("common.php");
    $primary = $_POST['primary'];
    $secondary = $_POST['secondary'];
    $not =  explode(',', $_POST['not']) ;
    //echo("primary: "+$primary+", secondary: "+$secondary+", not: "+$not);
    echo($primary);
?>
```

Comment: This does it! Thanks.